# mapping user-defined class as key to other user-defined class in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, key, stdmap, user-defined

I have created two classes: `Bank` and `Account`.

I would like to use `std::map<Bank, Account> bankAccount`, like this:

```
bankAccount.insert(std::make_pair(bank1, account1));
```

but I get several compile-time errors.

I know how to use `map<int, Bank>` or `map<int, Account>`, but not `map<Bank, Account>`.  I'm assuming the problem lies in telling the compiler how to ensure my `Bank` objects are unique, and since maps in C++ are ordered, I need to tell the compiler how to order the banks. This is no problem for the compiler if the key happens to be an integer.

My classes are as follows:

```
class Bank {
public:
    // Constructors
    Bank() = default;
    Bank(std::string name, std::string created, int balance, bool active)
            : m_name(std::move(name)), m_created(std::move(created)), m_balance(balance),   m_active(active) {};

    // Member functions
    void deposit(int amount) {
        m_balance += amount;
    }
    [[nodiscard]] int getBalance() const {
        return m_balance;
    }

    void setBalance(int amount) {
        m_balance = amount;
    }

    // Member attributes
    std::string m_name;
    std::string m_created;
    int m_balance{};
    bool m_active{};
};

class Account {
public:
    // Constructor
    Account() = default;
    Account(std::string name, int balance){
        m_name = name;
        m_balance = balance;
    }

    //Member functions
    void displayBalance() const {
        std::cout << m_name << ": " << m_balance << std::endl;
    }

    // Member attributes
    std::string m_name;
    int m_balance{};
};
```

A bank object is created as follows:

```
Bank bank1("FirstBank", "2015-01-01", 1000, true);
```

An account object is created as follows:

```
Account account1("Dining", 10000);
```

Can anyone please tell me how I can go about using my `Bank` class as a key to `std::map`?

I tried overloading `operator<()` in the `Bank` class as follows, but that didn't solve my problem:

```
bool operator<(Bank& other) {
    return m_name < other.m_name && m_created < other.m_created \
        && m_balance < other.m_balance && m_active < other.m_active;
}
```

Switching from `std::map` to `std::unordered_map` doesn't eliminate the compile-time errors, either.

Comment: What does "it didn't solve my problem" mean?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/5754656 (`friend bool operator<(const Bank& left, const Bank& right)`, or at least `bool operator<(const Bank& other) const`)

Comment: Your suggestion to modify the bool operator<() worked!  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Overloading `operator<` for your `Bank` class is the correct solution. However, your implementation of it is wrong, which will cause compile-time errors at best, and *undefined behavior* at runtime at worse.

Try something more like this instead:

```
class Bank {
public:
    ...

    bool operator<(const Bank& other) const {
        if (m_name < other.m_name)
            return true;
        if (m_name > other.m_name)
            return false;
        // m_name and other.m_name must be equal, keep comparing...

        if (m_created < other.m_created)
            return true;
        if (m_created > other.m_created)
            return false;
        // m_created and other.m_created must be equal, keep comparing...

        if (m_balance < other.m_balance)
            return true;
        if (m_balance > other.m_balance)
            return false;
        // m_balance and other.m_balance must be equal, keep comparing...

        return m_active < other.m_active;
    }
};
```

Alternatively:

```
class Bank {
public:
    ...
};

bool operator<(const Bank& b1, const Bank& b2)
{
    if (b1.m_name < b2.m_name)
        return true;
    // and so on, as shown above ...
}
```

Either way, the implementation of the operator can be greatly simplified by [`std::tie()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)'ing the values together, as `std::tie` already implements `operator<`, eg:

```
class Bank {
public:
    ...

    bool operator<(const Bank& other) const {
        return std::tie(m_name, m_created, m_balance, m_active) < std::tie(other.m_name, other.m_created, other.m_balance, other.m_active);
    }
}
```

Or:

```
class Bank {
public:
    ...
};

bool operator<(const Bank& b1, const Bank& b2) {
    return std::tie(b1.m_name, b1.m_created, b1.m_balance, b1.m_active) < std::tie(b2.m_name, b2.m_created, b2.m_balance, b2.m_active);
}
```